# Please tell me which tool I have to use to create a video?

Tags: video, video-editor, animation, compositing

I want to create a video as in the link below, the effect I want to create is that of a camera moving over a collection still photos and briefly pausing on each one:

[Youtube Link to video - iit Madras saarang teser 2009 - India](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMtediFgRaU)

Can anyone suggest me which tool I can use to create such video??
I have some images only. How can I achieve this kind of path navigation effect?

PS: Provide some video links created by those tools you are suggesting, so that I can close this Question based on that (and upvotes).

**UPDATED : QUERY ON AN EFFECT IN ABOVE LINKED VIDEO**
Hi all thanks for the help. I am good with after effects, its nice. In between I want to know one more thing how can I create an effect as in the above video (39th sec to 41st sec), transition from one plane to another, is there any special name for these kind of effect??

Comment: Adobe After Effects

Comment: The video you linked to was probably created in one of the software packages below. But it's impossible to tell from a video which tool it was created in.

Comment: @stib Thanks. I am deciding to go with after effects.

Comment: Good luck with it.

Comment: Hi all thanks for the help. I am good with after effects, its nice. In between I want to know one more thing how can I create an effect as in the above video (39th sec to 41st sec), transition from one plane to another, is there any special name for these kind of effect??

Comment: Some what I am able to create what i was planned with after effects, thanks : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9C961h34kv4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Effects could certainly do what you want, as could Apple Motion (only for Macs though). If you're on a budget you might want to look at something lower cost - or free:

- [Natron](http://natron.inria.fr/) is an open source free compositor, that will be able to do that effect
- [Blender](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-compositor/) - as well as being a 3D animation package it has a compositor too

[compositing](/questions/tagged/compositing) is the technique of combining images and video, so if you want to research more, what you need to search for is compositing software.

Comment: +1 for that suggetions. 
I know I might be annoyingm but still as new bee to this,  Is it posible to provide some video links created by these tools, which had almost those effects which are in my video too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am good with after effects, its nice. In between I want to know one more thing how can I create a effect as in the above video (39th sec to 41st sec), transition from one plane to another, is there any special name for these kind of effect??

Comment: Thanks and I am able to replicate some what of it as using after effects. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9C961h34kv4

Answer (score 3):

After Effects is a good, reasonably priced solution. If you're not on a tight schedule and on a tight budget, The Foundry is releasing a noncommercial version of their Nuke compositing platform, which is much more powerful than After Effects, sometime soon.

Comment: +1 for that suggetion. 
I know I might be annoyingm but still as new bee to this,  Is it posible to provide some video links created by these tools, which had almost those effects which are in my video too.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am good with after effects, its nice. In between I want to know one more thing how can I create an effect as in the above video (39th sec to 41st sec), transition from one plane to another, is there any special name for these kind of effect??